# JavaScript Follow / Unfollow Button

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, linux

I would like to make a simple JavaScript program witch allow you to like and dislike.
So actually I am new in JavaScript it's a bit difficult me yet.
So when you click onto the Follow button it will increase the "countF" variable's amount with 1, and change the button text to "Unfollow".
So as I said it is a basic program.
So I don't know how to acually do it in reverse. I mean when the Unfollow button has clicked the "countF" should decrease with 1, and the button text should change back to "Follow".
Yeah I know it's simple too, but somehow I can't do it.
Any help or idea how to finish this?

```js
var countF = 0;
var btnText = "Unfollow";
var countButton = document.getElementById("followButton");
var displayCount = document.getElementById("followers");
countButton.onclick = function() {
countF++;
followers.innerHTML = countF;
var countButton = document.getElementById("followButton");
countButton.innerHTML = btnText;
if(countButton.innerHTML = btnText) {
countF--;
countButton.innerHTML = "Follow";
}
}
```

```html
<div id="followers">0</div>
<button id="followButton"></button>
```

Comment: is the value only 1 or can it be greater than 1?

Comment: It should be greater than 1.

Comment: maybe then it would be more logical to make two buttons? - `Follow` and `Unfollow`

Comment: Yeah it would, but I would like to make it with one button.

Comment: If your value is greater than 1, then you will not be able to do this with one button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
var countF = 0;
var countButton = document.getElementById("followButton");
var displayCount = document.getElementById("followers");
countButton.onclick = function() {
if (countButton.innerText == "Follow") {
    countF++;
    countButton.innerText = "Unfollow";
  } else if (countButton.innerText == "Unfollow") {
    countF--;
    countButton.innerText = "Follow";
  }
  followers.innerHTML = countF;
}
```

And add text to your button:

```
<button id="followButton">Follow</button>
```

Comment: But in this case, the value will never be greater than 1.

Answer (score 2):

Check this video out for a great tutorial on voting systems. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBPURBO1kD8 Whenever you have voting you need to handle the voting with more than just the client side.

With that being said, maybe this concept would help:

```
let likedPost = false

function toggleVote() {
    likedPost ? removeUpvote() : addUpvote()
    likedPost = !likedPost
}

function removeUpvote() {
    //code for removing
    //probably should be a few calls to a server
}
function addUpvote() {
    //code for adding
    //probably should be a few calls to a server
}
```